# Integrate unit testing for appsync mapping templates in serverless framework

Tags: unit-testing, graphql, serverless-framework, aws-appsync

Is there a method to create unit tests to test the queries and mutations of AWS AppSync before deploying it(using serverless framework).

I have created appsync api and data source is relational database, but now i want to integrate test case for all queries and mutations which are in vtx file format  but not getting relevant information.